# In Django, how do I deal with an "or" in the url regex once I get to the view?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm just learning Django, and am getting stuck with some url logic. I'm trying to allow either a category name or id in the url:

```
...
url(r'^(?P<booze_q>\w+|\d+)/$','glasses.views.booze'),
...
```

And then in thew view, only deal with that result once. However, if the url is a string - in this case, `Whiskey`, I get an error for trying to pass a string where an int is expected. This is the closest I've gotten so far:

```
def booze(request, booze_q):
    booze = get_object_or_404(Booze,Q(pk=booze_q)|Q(name=booze_q))
    return render_to_response('booze/detail.html', {'booze': booze})
```

But this returns an error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Whiskey'`

I'm sure it's a pretty easy thing, but this is my first Django app, so any help would be appreciated.

**tl;dr**: End result, I'd like `mysite.com/1/` or `mysite.com/Whiskey/` to both call the `glasses.views.booze` view, and get the object with `id=1` or `name=Whiskey`

Comment: Where is the error being raised?  Does the stack trace show it coming from your view, or somewhere in django's internals?

Comment: @TM it looks like in the view. Full trace: https://gist.github.com/1131129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always get a string, even if the string contains a number.

1) You should *not* have a parameter that could be either an id or something else. One day you will enter an item whose name is a number and your app will fail.

2) When querying for `pk` with a string django automatically tries to convert it into an integer. You'll have to handle the non-pk case before constructing that query.

Comment: So would it make sense in the view to do a regex check for str vs int, and act accordingly? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Of course there is a better way, since this is the wrong way. Read my answer: you should _not_ have a parameter that can be either or. Use a different URL for ids.

Comment: Gotchya. "Use a different URL for ids" will work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible, with two urls, to call one def in the view? Or do I need to have two defs as well?

Comment: Of course that is possible. Please don't use this comment thread for further discussions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario you'll encounter quite often, which is typically handled by resorting to multiple arguments and having views behave differently based on which of the view arguments are then present or not.

What you do is first define a URL pattern that uniquely matches each specific case and then let Django's URL resolver set the arguments accordingly based on which of the patterns was matched.

Here's an example with a class based view, that performs two different queries based on which of the two keyword arguments, `booze_id` or `booze_name`, is set:

```
url(r'^(?P<booze_id>\d+)/$', BoozeDetailView.as_view()),
url(r'^(?P<booze_name>\w+)/$', BoozeDetailView.as_view()),

class BoozeDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Booze

    def get_object(self):
        booze_id = self.kwargs.get('booze_id', None)
        booze_name = self.kwargs.get('booze_name', None)

        if booze_id:
            return self.model.objects.get(id=booze_id)
        else:
            return self.model.objects.get(name=booze_name)
```

Comment: That's essentially what I ended up doing last night. Thanks for the detail!